# API does not return updated date for calendar event

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, api

### Situation

A user creates calendar events in SPO. We use PowerAutomate to send an email once a week with a listing of the events that will take place in the next two weeks.

### Problem

Sometimes, the date must be corrected. Once the date is corrected in SPO, the email still contains the original date.

### What I have tried

I have pulled the full list of events with all available fields, but I cannot find the new date.

These are the fields available in properties: FileSystemObjectType, Id, ServerRedirectedEmbedUri, ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl, ID, ContentTypeId, Title, Modified, Created, AuthorId, EditorId, OData__UIVersionString, Attachments, GUID, OData__ColorTag, ComplianceAssetId, Location, Geolocation, EventDate, EndDate, Description, fAllDayEvent, fRecurrence, ParticipantsPickerId, ParticipantsPickerStringId, Category, FreeBusy, Overbook, BannerUrl, Description, Url, BannerImageUrl.

The only date field used today is EventDate. That shows the original date for the event.

Is there another field that does not typically come in on a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/

Calendar events are stored in a list on SharePoint. The `EventDate` field is where the date of the event is usually stored.

From the fields you've shown, there doesn't seem to be another place where this new date could be.

Something else in your system is stopping the new date from being saved in the `EventDate` field.

As a workaround, make a new field where you can save the new date. Then, you can change your PowerAutomate flow to use this new field.